# Install from DVD, NSIS

Tags: nsis

I need to prompt user to insert second Disc to continue installation. I am able to prompt user to insert Disc but how do I detect whether the user inserted a Disc or not, and if Inserted I need to run the setup.exe file from the DVD.

```
MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION  "Insert disc to install User Software or Click No to    proceed" /SD IDNO IDYES yes IDNO no
    yes:
        Call installUserSoftware
no: 
   ;do nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the code in the answers to your other questions you should now have enough information about enumerating and detecting drives.

To detect the correct drive you need to look for something specific on the disc, it can be as simple as using `IfFileExists` on a file with a known name or maybe try reading something from a .ini file you know exists on the drive with a certain value (`ReadINIStr`). You could even check the version information on a .exe or .dll with `GetDLLVersion`.